# DocuSign Arabic text

Tags: docusignapi

I 'am using DocuSign API for migrating Arabic text inserted by a user through a web form. The problem is that the user details will appear as question marks instead of the Arabic text:

[image: question marks instead of text]

Besides, the user can modify the name again when the API is called.

I would like to show the real name and make the text areas disabled so only the info migrated will be shown.

Comment: You want the user details to appear as question marks or the problem is that Arabic text is being shown as question marks?

Comment: The problem is that Arabic text is being shown as question marks

Comment: Please add to your question and show how you are setting the text field value. Are you using JSON or XML?

Answer (score 1):

You can set text fields to be read only by setting the `locked` field to "true" when you create the field.

DocuSign does support the entry of Arabic text into fields. Here is an example: I entered the text into the field while signing via DocuSign. The final pdf then shows the text:

[image]

If you want to hide information in a field, use the `concealValueOnDocument` field when creating the tab.